Closed form for the recurrence $S_n = 1 + S_{n-1} + \frac{2}{n} S_{n-2}$, where $S_1=1$ and $S_2=2$?

How would you go about getting an expression for $S_n$ where $S_1=1$, $S_2=2$, and $S_n = 1 + S_{n-1} + \frac{2}{n} S_{n-2}$?

I'm using this to try and solve a separate problem which involves the relation $E_n = 1 + \frac{2}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n-2}E_i$ where $E_1 = 1$. In this case $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n E_i$.
I've read a few papers on hypergeometric functions in these cases, but they either seem not applicable to this situation or fly right over my head.
Any help would be much appreciated!

With the definition, what is $E_2$ ? Is there a typo ? Could you list the first $E_i$'s ? Thanks

Ah apologies - for any index $i$ less than 1, $E_i$ is 0. So the sequence would be 1, 1, 5/3, 2, ...

I went for a power series expansion and found $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty S_n x^n = \frac{1-e^{-2x}}{2(1-x)^3}~.$$
From here you can use the cauchy product to gain an explicit description of the sequence.
$$S_n = \frac{-1}{4} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-2)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!} (k+2)(k+1)$$
I will try to answer all your questions, just ask.
Yes power series expansions are a common method for solving recurrence relations or proving properties of sequences. The central idea is that the power series $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k$$ contains every information that we could know about the sequence $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$. We can then apply known results from analysis to solve for the sequence by interpreting  the power series as a function of $x$. This function is called the generating function of $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ (or ordinary generating function). Lets call the function for your sequence $P$ that is $$P(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty S_n x^n~.$$ I will not go over formal power series (look that up on your own if you are interested!). Hence, I would have to argue that $P$ is well defined. Therefore I have to find a region for $x$ where I know the series converges. In this case this is quite trivial.
How do we solve for $S_n$?. We use the known recurrence relation to find an explicit description of $P$. Note that if if $S_n$ is some messy term $P$ can be quit simple (Does not have to be the case, but works out). To motivate this step it is important to notice that it is easy to reexpand a given function as power series with Taylors theorem, known expantions and the cauchy product (an some other tricks...). For the example we start like so with $S_0 = S_{-1} = 0$ by the recurrence relation:
$$P(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty S_n x^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (1+ S_{n-1}+ \frac{2}{n} S_{n-2}) x^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n + \sum_{n=1}^\infty S_{n-1} x^n + 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{S_{n-2}}{n} x^n$$ We
can shift the sums and find the definition of $P$ again. Also using the geometric sum furmula here:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n + \sum_{n=1}^\infty S_{n-1} x^n + 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty S_{n-2} x^n = \frac{x}{1-x} + x P(x) +  2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{S_{n-2}}{n} x^n ~.$$
The last sum is a bit more tricky. To solve it we take the derivative of the whole eqaution, because $$ \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{S_{n-2}}{n} x^n= \sum_{n=1}^\infty {S_{n-2}} x^{n-1}~.$$
Combining all of this leads to a differential equaion in $P$, which  can be solved (with or without a computer programm) directly! This leads to the first result I claimed in my initial answer. From here I noticed that one could use the cauchy product to extract a closed expression.
I have a decent amount of experience with series expansions. For this question it only took a few seconds to see how a series approach would work out. I then decided to do the calculation myself (Pro: I knew before starting that I would hit the desired result, Con: It is still quit a lot of calc to do and the answer as whole is rarely elegant).
I hope this was detailed enough.

My friend who posed me the problem asks: "how did you derive the power series thing pls pls pls >_< ". I'd also like to ask how did you resort to using a power series as your tool of choice - is it a common way of solving these kinds of questions?

I am busy right now... I will give a detailed explanation later.

@ojt I added a short answer to your questions. I recommend looking  a simple example to understand the power series approach (maybe look for the Binet equation for the fibonacci numbers , this is a nice example). Of course you should know some calculus or analysis for this.

Tis is a beautiful and very elegant solution.

Too long for a comment.
After reading the more than elegant solution provided by @M.E.W., consider
$$S_n(a)=-\frac{1}{4} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{a^{n-k}}{(n-k)!} (k+2)(k+1)$$ the summation is given in terms of the exponential integral function. Fortunately, this simplify and give in terms of the complete and incomplete gamma function
$$S_n(a)=\frac{(a-n-2) a^{n+1}-e^a \left(a^2-2  a (n+1)+(n+1) (n+2)\right) \Gamma
   (n+1,a)+\Gamma (n+3)}{4 \Gamma (n+1)}$$ and then
$$S_n(-2)=\frac{1}{4} (n+1) (n+2) +(-1)^n\frac{ \,2^{n-1} \,(n+4)}{\Gamma
   (n+1)}-\frac{(n+2)\, (n+5)\, \Gamma (n+1,-2)}{4\,
   e^2\, \Gamma (n+1)}$$ which, starting at $n=1$, generates the sequence
$$\left\{1,2,\frac{11}{3},\frac{17}{3}
   ,\frac{122}{15},\frac{496}{45},\frac{4519}{315},\frac{5702}{315},\frac
   {63191}{2835},\frac{381448}{14175},\cdots\right\}$$
